# Gaps in ggplot2 pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create pie charts that shows market shares of several products. I want to facet wrap the pie charts this way that I show market share of products before and after the introduction of the product X[image: .]

However, as in the period 0 this product was non-existent, my pie chart is not closing.
I tried to introduce additional row in the data set for this product X in the period 0 (binary coded variable) and set all market statistics to zeros, hoping that the pie chart will be fixed, but it did not work and now I have zero on top.

the code is following:

```
ggplot(df_graph,aes(x="", y=sales, fill=Product.Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta="y")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="time_period")+
  facet_wrap(~before_1345)+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text=element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size=12,color="black"),plot.margin = margin(c(10,1,10,1)))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Share_x*100, 2), "%")),family = "Times New Roman",size=4,position=position_stack(vjust=0.6),color="black",angle=45) + 
  labs(fill = "Product")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that the pie charts aren't filled because the bar chart in cartesian coordinates don't have the same height.

Roughly reproducing the problem with a built-in dataset, we can see that when we have bars of unequal heights in cartesian coordinates...

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = "", y = displ, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ year)
```

[image]

... don't fill the pie chart when using polar coordinates:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = "", y = displ, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ year)
```

[image]

This is easy to remedy by setting `position = "fill"` in the bar layer.

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = "", y = displ, fill = class)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ year)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>